# UIPageViewController delayed when pressing indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, pageviews, pagecontrol

I have problem in my app with indicator changing color for specific view.

My app has 4 viewControllers with different colors contained in PageViewController class.

I've set PageViewController view.backgroundcolor to match current viewControllers view.backgroundcolor. It has some twitches when swiping (sometimes color stays from last viewController), but when i press indicator color of indicator stays from last viewController.

[Video of bug](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqdBwMuF6Zg&feature=youtu.be)

Did you have similar issue or is there better solution than changing backgroundcolor?